# DRY principles between frontend and backend

Tags: oop, dry

During my programming practice I very often become faced with a problem of data duplication between client-side and server-side scripts. 
In this context we can talk about JavaScript on client-side and PHP or C# (ASP.NET) on server-side.

Let's say, I have a JavaScript code that defines a constant (or array, or object) with specific data. E.g. it can be data that references to app business rules. This data also should be used at backend and I have to define this constant in appropriate script.

And in this moment, when we defined the second variable, we have violated the principle "Don't repeat yourself". For now, when I change this constant on frontend, I have to change this constant on backend too.

And amount of coupled in this way data can grow up, and my code will be very hard to maintain in future.

So, my question is next: is there any ways, or good practices to follow DRY principles in context of client-server communication? For example, is it good practice to keep this kind of data in .settings files and read it both on frontend and backend?

Answer (score 0):

DRY principal applies to Repetition in logic and not necessarily means not using same variables across the frontend and bakend. If such a case applies, then using of view models and DTO's would voilate the DRY principal. You need to seperate your concerns of the UI with other layers. Your UI might change but your business logic should not be scattered across with duplicate code which might make maintainability a nightmare. Take a look at automapper and understand the concept of object mapping which might probably remove your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on wikipedia, DRY is stated as

> Every piece of knowledge must have a single, unambiguous,
>   authoritative representation within a system

Therefore your duplicated knowledge in different layer, violates DRY.

Having such constants defined many places can be quite a problem later on. Worse will be when you want to configurable the constants. Fortunately you can quite solve the problem with setting the javascript variable from server.

e.g in php:

```
var constants = <?php echo JSONConstants($constants); ?>;
console.log(constants.companyName);
```

You just need to make sure that the script is executed before any business logic script in javascript loaded. Furthermore, you need to take care of which constants (and build it in some nice structure) which will be passed to javascript for easier development.

Comment: Thank you! And do you know any ways to avoid duplication when we refer to html elements from JavaScript code by their ID? E.g. $("#someElementId") refers to some element. If I decide to change element's ID in HTML, what should I do then with my JavaScript? Review all my code and search every "someElementId" to change it? Even this ID was mentioned only once in JavaScript we can face with some problems if we will a little inattentive. This question bothers me not less than subject question :)

Comment: You can ask another question for that since the answer is quite long